# Does the divine council in Psalm 82 correspond to different religions that we see in the world today?

Tags: genesis, old-testament, comparative-religion, psalms, gods

I read the book **Unseen Realm** by Michael Heiser a few years ago. In that book, Dr. Heiser begins the book by talking about how Psalm 82 opened his eyes to the council of multiple gods in the divine council. If I understand Dr. Heiser correctly, he then goes on to point out 3 different turning points in man's falling away from the Most High God, namely the fall in Eden in Genesis 3, the rise of the Nephilim in Genesis 6, and then the dispersion of mankind after Babel in Genesis 11. After Babel, then the Most High God takes it upon Himself to redeem mankind through Abraham and Abraham's descendants. According to Dr. Heiser, when the Most High God focused on building a relationship with Abraham and his descendants, then the Most High God also left the management of the other peoples of the earth to the other members of the council of the gods. Psalm 82 is then a condemnation by the Most High God of these other gods not doing their job very well.

My question concerns whether there is any evidence that these other gods in the council of the gods can be seen as the gods that we now see in different world religions, like those found in Hinduism, Islam, Zoroastrianism, Shintoism, and so forth. Is there any evidence in other scriptures that might suggest such a connection? In other words, do the gods of the divine council found in Psalm 82 correspond to the gods found in world religions today?

Comment: Interesting speculation.  But I don't think Dr. Heiser himself understood it that way from the hints we could glean from the OT + the 2nd temple materials.  I need to confirm this, but it seems Dr. Heiser proposed, implied in [a book review](https://www.thegospelcoalition.org/themelios/review/the-unseen-realm-recovering-the-supernatural-worldview-of-the-bible/): "In his victory God will be accompanied by both loyal members of the divine council and believers who have displaced the corrupt gods of the nations."  [This book](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/1620329743) may address it too.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs in BH.SE.

Comment: I have significant issue with this statement in the OP..."After Babel, then the Most High God takes it upon Himself to redeem mankind through Abraham and Abraham's descendants."  If true its heresy (the plan of salvation was clearly spoken of in Genesis Ch3:15!)

Comment: @Adam - Apologies if I did not phrase that in the best way. Genesis 3:15 shows that the covenant for salvation was to all mankind that was fulfilled through Christ. But then there were other covenants with Abraham and his descendants through whom God fulfilled that original promise by the coming of Christ. So, no heresy intended by Dr. Heiser, I am sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, "NO." And yes, I have read what Michael Heiser has written regarding Psalm 82:6. I don't think anyone TRANSLATES "Ellohiym" here as "judges." That is not a proper translation. The most literal TRANSLATION is "powers" or "mighty (ones)' - and invariably refers to those that have power and authority (whether this power is real and righteous or divine, or inherent, or imparted or imaginary or corrupt is determined by the CONTEXT).

The CONTEXT of the psalm clearly identifies the referent of the term. It clearly says that these "elohium" "judge," i.e perform the act of judgement, and do so unjustly (v.2). That would make them "judges" by definition, and corrupt judges at that.

After identifying their corrupt judgment, it goes on (vs.3-4) to admonish these judges (these who are "judging" unjustly) to correct their behavior by defending the needy from the hand of the wicked.

The Psalmist goes on to bemoan the ignorance and darkness of the powerful being about whom he is complaining and attributes the disharmonious conditions in his world (the "out of course" condition of the "foundations of the earth") to them at vs 5.

At vs. 6, we find the declaration that these who are doing all this corrupt judgment are "gods" (elohiym") and children (sons) of God (the most High). However... IN CONTEXT the next sentence is introduced with the conjunction of contrast "But" (Hebrew. 'aken' most assuredly") and clearly shows that while someone (presumably God) has called and by contrast, experience the universal division between gods and men - they will DIE despite their power and authority (vs. 7).

Clearly the subjects of the term "Elohiym" are powerful beings (again the most literal translation of the term) who are executing judgments (and do poorly). That would make them "judges" BY DEFINITION, even though the word "elohiym DOES NOT MEAN ONTOLOGICAL DEITIES?

In fact, Jesus Christ explicitly identifies the ones "called gods" in Psalm 82 as those "to whom the word of God came." That could ONLY be the Israelites in general and, given the context of the Psalm, concerned with righteous judgment as it clearly is-those who were empowered by that word to JUDGE in Israel. It's pretty obvious. So obvious (I believe) in fact that I don't think Heiser has a valid argument AGAINST it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. To clarify, it seems that your stance is that Dr. Heiser's exegesis of Psalm 82 is not accurate. You would base this primarily on the quote from Jesus in John 10:34-35 that uses this quote from Psalm 82:6. And then Jesus says that this saying of being gods was given to those "whom the word of God came", and so this must be the Jews. I suppose this would go along more with the footnote for 82:1 in the CEV: the other gods: This probably refers to the gods of the nations that God defeated, but it could refer to God’s servants (angels) in heaven or even to human rulers.

Comment: @bkudrle Your welcome! I would base Dr. Heiser's exegesis of Psalm 82:6 as "eisegesis," reading into the text, that's all I'm saying. And the CEV is more of a paraphrase like the Living Bible. Also, regarding vs1 it does say literally say "gods" but vs2 says, "How long will you judge unjustly." Supporting my viewpoint. Don't get me wrong, I agree with Dr. Heiser's take or article he wrote regarding the angel of the Lord in the Old Testament. Do you happen to know why Jesus quoted Psalm 82:6?

Comment: Before this, I took the reply of Jesus to the Jews as a defense that they had no right to charge Him with blasphemy about being the son of God because even their scriptures talked about the existence of gods. That may be a very incomplete interpretation, though, as I study this further. It is making sense to me now that, as you say, these 'Ellohiym' are men who were 'gods' in the sense of having great authority over the people. As you said, though, they will die like men, as 82:7 says. And they had received the word of God, which would suggest that they were Jews.

Comment: @bkudrle  Regarding Jesus quoting Psalm 82:6. When He cites Psalm 82:6 at John 10:34 He establishes the mode of argument by comparing two things. If scripture was not in error calling mortals "gods" then neither is there error in calling the one whom God consecrated and sent into the world the Son of God. His reference to "Son of God," does not weaken His argument but bolsters it. In claiming to be the consecrated Son of God He does not claim less than what is claimed by being "god" according to Psalm 82:6. On the contrary, He claims more. The Jews understood, otherwise no charge of blasphemy.